# Using distractor.analysis of R CTT library on items with missing responses

Tags: r

R and stat noob here. I have been playing with Jeromy Anglim's code in his blog post [here](http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2010/11/sweave-tutorial-3-console-input-and.html). However, my `items$variable` has some missing values. I tried using the `distractor.analysis` function from the `CTT` package with

```
distractor.analysis(cases[,items$variable], items$correct)
```

I get the error

```
Error : missing values and NaN ’s not allowed if ’na .rm ’ is FALSE
```

Is there a work-around for using `distractor.analysis` for data with missing responses or is there a better way to perform distractor analysis in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While uploading the `.csv` or `.xlsx` file into R console, keep all the cells containing `NA` just blank. It would work fine for **'distractor analysis'** under `CTT Library`.

Further, if the missing cells would be filled up by **X**, then also the `distractor.analysis()` function under `CTT library` would work. Hence, the output would be prettier and the row of **'number of candidates who have not attempted the item'** would be assigned by `X`.

It would be wiser to denote all the missing cells by `X`. That is a find/replace task in that Excel file only.   `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You can remove rows which have NaN values from your response matrix like this:

```
distractor.analysis(na.omit(cases[,items$variable]), items$correct)
```

Alternatively, you can assign a different value to the NaN cells in your `data.frame` [like this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-replace-all-lt-NA-gt-values-in-a-data-frame-with-another-not-0-value-td2125458.html). This way, you can still use your full dataset and also analyse missing values, if you wish.

Comment: These two topics seem to be linked, which may be helpful for others to know about in the future: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144470/is-it-possible-to-do-irt-distractor-analysis-using-r

Comment: Hi @DouglasDeRizzoMeneghetti, thanks. I totally forgot I asked this question here. I have since studied subsetting in R and your solution was exactly how I did it. I should have answered my own question but I forgot I even asked it here. But I am amazed at how long it took to answer this question. Thank you.

Comment: It was a coincidence I had to do just that a few days ago, using the very same package. I found this question when searching the site for something similar, which @philchalmers taught me how to do two comments up.