# Is it possible to do IRT distractor analysis using R?

Tags: psychometrics, item-response-theory

I've been using the `mirt` package to analyse a few response matrixes I have through IRT. However, every time I need to perform distractor analysis, I end up having to go back to Classical Test Theory package `CTT`. Is it possible to use `mirt` (or any other package, for that matter) to analyse distractors via IRT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, and I have found this quite useful in the past. Simply fit something flexible that captures information from each category, like the nominal response model, to the items of interest, and inspect the response curves graphically or by looking at the scoring/ordering coefficients and intercepts. That will give you an indication of how the distractors are behaving, and actually whether you correctly scored items in the first place (sometimes, they aren't scored correctly, and this is a good method to detect that because the 'correct' category will not be consistently increasing as $\theta$ increases).

Note that this has all the benefits of IRT as well (i.e., effective handling of missing data, computation of factor scores, etc) and works for multidimensional testing situations too by inspecting the respective scoring coefficients (the plots can be too high dimensional to create for some tests). See the [mirt wiki](https://github.com/philchalmers/mirt/wiki), specifically the exercise files from the workshop in Zurich, for examples.

Comment: I just saw example 2 from your Zurich examples and I realized that, if you pass the nominal response matrix instead of the binary one to the `mirt` function, it allows one to plot the probability curves of each alternative, which is really nice to analyse distractors. Thanks @philchalmers.

Comment: Just a quick question @philchalmers. In order to see the probability curves for each alternative, the right way to do it is by setting the `itemtype` to 'nominal' just like your example? If I do that, I don't get to see which one is the correct alternative in the plots?

Comment: @DouglasDeRizzoMeneghetti that's correct, because the correct category is not imposed in the modelling. You'll want to plot the item with `itemplot(mod, item)`, and compare the highest category to the correct scoring key. So if the third category was supposed to be the correct answer, then you should see a 2PL-like increasing trace-line for the third category.